# TableLayout not displaying its parents according to its weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display 3 rows in a row But with weights 70,30 and 30 But when I assign weights to those I am not getting the output properly
What should I do, Please help me
i am new to android

I have tried with the code given below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/White" />

<TableLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@id/bAdd_add"
     android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
     android:showDividers="1"
     >



     <TableRow 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center">
         <TextView 
             android:text="@string/add_sku"
             android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:background="@drawable/info_row"
             android:layout_weight="70"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
             android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
         <TextView 
             android:text="@string/add_rate"
             android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:textSize="20sp"
              android:background="@drawable/info_row"
             android:layout_weight="30"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
         <TextView 
             android:text="@string/add_qt"
             android:textColor="@color/White"
             android:textSize="20sp"
              android:background="@drawable/info_row"
             android:layout_weight="30"
             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
             android:paddingTop="10dp"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

     </TableRow>



 </TableLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivAdd_gray"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gray"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my technique within the linear layout add an relative layout that will handle the objects and assign the object 1;android:layout_weight="0.2" object2;android:layout_weight="0.2" object3;android:layout_weight="0.6"

```
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView3"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:text="Surcarge"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />

          <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_fadingButton2"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
      android:layout_weight="1">

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText_Surcharge"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:ems="8"
         android:enabled="false"
         android:inputType="numberDecimal"
         android:minWidth="100dp"
         android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText_Interest" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/FadingButton_surcharge"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
          android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAdd_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bAdd_add"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:background="@drawable/info_row"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add_sku"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@drawable/info_row"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add_rate"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:background="@drawable/info_row"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add_qt"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```